# Xamarin PCL how to add data attribute to existing partial classes (fields)

Tags: c#, attributes, xamarin.forms, code-generation, partial-classes

We have an autogenerated class with a field id and we want to add a data attribute [PrimaryKey] to it.
The problem we got is that it doesn't recognize [MetadataType] even though we have the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations packages added.

Code class with data attribute:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ZoekenMetaData))] // this where we get the error on Metadata
public partial class Zoeken
{
    internal sealed class ZoekenMetaData
    {
        [PrimaryKey]

        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The auto generated class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "Zoeken", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OurWCF")]
public partial class Zoeken : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private string AdresField;


    private string GemeenteField;


    private System.Guid IdField;


    private string NaamField;


    private string TelefoonField;


    private string TypeField;


    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Adres
    {
        get
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AdresField) ? "Onbekend" : this.AdresField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.AdresField, value) != true))
            {
                this.AdresField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Adres");
            }
        }
    }


    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Gemeente
    {
        get
        {
            //return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GemeenteField) ? "Onbekend" : this.GemeenteField;
            return this.GemeenteField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.GemeenteField, value) != true))
            {
                this.GemeenteField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Gemeente");
            }
        }
    }


    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
     public System.Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IdField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.IdField.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                this.IdField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Naam
    {
        get
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NaamField) ? "Onbekend" : this.NaamField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.NaamField, value) != true))
            {
                this.NaamField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Naam");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Telefoon
    {
        get
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TelefoonField) ? "Onbekend" : this.TelefoonField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.TelefoonField, value) != true))
            {
                this.TelefoonField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Telefoon");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TypeField) ? "Onbekend" : this.TypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.TypeField, value) != true))
            {
                this.TypeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is also a screenshot of the error
[ErrorMetadatType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqqsn.png)

edit trying to change the profile:
[EditImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X684.png)

Comment: https://github.com/ryanhorath/PortableDataAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the PCL profile you are targeting. Have a look at this guide [here](http://danrigby.com/2014/04/16/xamarin-pcl-profile-notes/) by Dan Rigby. I see profile 44 mentioned with the annotations you are looking for.

> #### Profile 44 (.NET 4.5.1, Windows 8.1) (netstandard 1.2)
>
> Supported in Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.1+
>
> Similar to Profile 151, but includes access to data annotations and a subset of WCF APIs:
>
> - System.ComponentModel.Annotations
> - System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations System.ServiceModel
> - System.ServiceModel.Duplex System.ServiceModel.Http
> - System.ServiceModel.NetTcp System.ServiceModel.Primitives
> - System.ServiceModel.Security Most current and forward looking profile (at the expense of backward compatibility)

To change this profile, go into the properties of your PCL project.

Comment: I will include a picture of how i'm trying to solve this in my edit of my question. can you tell me if this is the correct way to do it and if i really have to uninstall all of my nuget packages?